# ISBLANK condition not working

Tags: apex, conditional

I want to display a button but only when two fields are matched (Category__c = Events & Custom_URL__c IS NOT BLANK).

```
<apex:outputLink value="/register" id="register" rendered="{!IF(AND(article.Category__c == 'Events', NOT(ISBLANK(article.Custom_URL__c))), TRUE, FALSE)}">
Register
</apex:outputLink>
```

But on items where Custom_URL__c is populated (with a URL) the link is still not shown.

I have done SOQL query to see what data is being recieved and the Custom_URL__c field is clearly populated in the record.

Comment: Have you tried reducing your condition to `{!NOT(ISBLANK(article.Custom_URL__c)}` to verify that it is just the URL part that is the issue?

Comment: I have yes, it is still not working

Comment: Add an [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) element to test out your formula. Start with a simple output such as `<apex:outputText value="{!article.Custom_URL__c)"/>` or `<apex:outputText value="{!'URL:' & article.Custom_URL__c)"/>` and then keep adding to it each time to verify the output is as expected.

Comment: The field was not shown, this leads me to believe the field is not visible under the current profile.

Comment: That would cause that type of problem alright.

Comment: Please write convert this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to debug these types of issues is too start with the simplest formula/condition and display it in an [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm) element. In your case you could start off with:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!article.Custom_URL__c)"/>
// OR this
<apex:outputText value="{!'URL:' & article.Custom_URL__c)"/>
```

You can then verify that the output is as you expected. Then add more and more to the formula, while checking the output as you go along.